# Technical name for 3.5mm microphone input and speaker output to headphone with microphone cable?

Tags: microphone

I am trying to find a cable online that takes the front jacks on my computer case (speaker out, audio in) and merges them so I can use my headphones that have a built in microphone.

What would I search to find what I am looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a TRS splitter.

[image: TRS female splitter]
<sub>(source: [littlesun.com.au](http://www.littlesun.com.au/images/201306/goods_img/66_G_1371475603007.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Incredible. That name brings up perfect results. Thankyou!